# repeat javascript funcitonality without multiple instances of same code in script

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, scripting

I have no working knowledge of Java script and am trying to get into it.

I have a PHP page with a table. The first column of the row has a drop down list. when the onclick event is triggered it populates the other cells in the row based on a php mysql query.

The problem is that my table can consist of up to 75 rows as it is for an order page. I'd prefer not to have the same javascropt code 75 times with a different pointer?

is there an easier way to do this in order to optimize the page and reduce the page complexity? (document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";)

Can I use $(this) at all? if so how do I integrate it? otherwise what are my options?

My php page is as below. currently it works with two rows however i need to provision for 75 rows.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showUser1(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }

 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showUser2(str)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'unilekxy_UL', 'Unilever2011');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("unilekxy_unilever", $con);


$skusql="SELECT packcode,concat(packcode, ' - ' , description) as description from skudata"; 
$resultsku=mysql_query($skusql); 

$optionssku=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultsku)) { 

    $sku=$row["packcode"]; 
    $description=$row["description"]; 
    $optionssku.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$sku\">".$description; 
} 

 ?>

<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td width=393>Product</td>
    <td width=200>Category</td>
    <td width=150>Selling Unit</td>
    <td width=150>Grouping</td>
    <td width=150>Full Case QTY</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser1(this.value)" size=1>
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint1"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser2(this.value)" size=1>
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint2"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>


</body>
 </html>
```

the php page that gets called to execute the mysql is

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("unilekxy_unilever", $con);

$sql="SELECT Category, SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet  FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<table border=1><tr>";
   echo "<td width=200>".$row['Category']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['SellingUnits']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['Grouping']."</td><td width=150>";
   if($row['SellingUnits']=="CS"){echo $row['CasesPerPallet'];} elseif($row['SellingUnits']=="SHR") {echo $row['ShrinksPerPallet'];}
   echo "</td></tr></table>";
   }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Thanks in advane for the help,
Ryan

Comment: Why not start by streamlining the JavaScript with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've touched on one of the most valuable principles of programming: Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY). Programming is all about seeking the most efficient way to do something. Anyway, here's the simplest way to rewrite your javascript function to be more generic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showUser(userNumber, str)
  {
    if (str=="")
    {
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

Now in each of your table rows, your select element becomes:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)" size=1>
```

Replacing '1' with the row number.

Using jQuery to grab the closest txtHint element would be an even better way to structure your code, but that's a little beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Thanks Amit, appreciate the effort you put into this answer. Working 100%.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can make it as generic function by passing an additional argument from the caller,

Modified Function, Please Note that the function name is changed to `showUser` and added additional argument `num` to identify from which row it is getting called.

```
function showUser(str, num)
 {
 if (str=="")
   {
   document.getElementById("txtHint" + num).innerHTML="";
   return;
   } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("txtHint" + num).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Modified HTML,  Please Note the change in the function name and an additional argument 1 which will be 2 for the next row and so on.

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value, 1)" size=1>
```

**Edit:**  Changed argument name from index to num, index is misleading since textHint starts from 1.

Answer (score 2):

here's the easy way :

```
showUser1(str)
```

become

```
showUser1(str, number)
```

and

```
document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
```

become

```
document.getElementById("txtHint"+number).innerHTML="";
```

in the html :

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser2(this.value)" size=1>
```

become

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value,2)" size=1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Write one common on change handler, and in the change handler get select element
and then `element.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild` would give your div tag, and then use its id for js element references and to make right php calls. This way all your html event subscripts would be same.

You can also write a php loop with a tr element (represeting a user) as the body, and then use the above approach to hook up javascript. This way both your html code and js code would be reduced and you dont even have to name them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would post the final solution here and full code. Big Thanks to @Amit whose answer I used. Thanks also to everyone who took the time to answer my questions, all very valuable.

**index.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
  document.getElementById("r"+(userNumber+1)).style.display="block";  
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else 
    {// code for IE6, IE5 
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 
</script> 

 </head>
 <body>
 <?

 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', DBUser', 'DBPass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);


$skusql="SELECT packcode,concat(packcode, ' - ' , description) as description from skudata"; 
$resultsku=mysql_query($skusql); 

$optionssku=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultsku)) { 

    $sku=$row["packcode"]; 
    $description=$row["description"]; 
    $optionssku.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$sku\">".$description; 
} 

 ?>

<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td width=393>Product</td>
    <td width=200>Category</td>
    <td width=150>Selling Unit</td>
    <td width=150>Grouping</td>
    <td width=150>Full Case QTY</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr id="r1">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint1"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r2" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint2"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r3" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint3"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r4" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(4, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint4"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="r5" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(5, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint5"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r6" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(6, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint6"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r7" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(7, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint7"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r8" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(8, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint8"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r9" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(9, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint9"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r10" style="display:none;">  
    <td>
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(10, this.value)"> 
        <OPTION VALUE=0>
        <?=$optionssku?> 
        </SELECT> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="txtHint10"><b>SKU Details will be seen here</b></div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
 </html>
```

**GetData1.php**

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'DBUser', 'DBPass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("DBName", $con);

$sql="SELECT Category, SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet  FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<table border=1><tr>";
   echo "<td width=200>".$row['Category']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['SellingUnits']."</td>";
   echo "<td width=150>".$row['Grouping']."</td><td width=150>";
   if($row['SellingUnits']=="CS"){echo $row['CasesPerPallet'];} elseif($row['SellingUnits']=="SHR") {echo $row['ShrinksPerPallet'];}
   echo "</td></tr></table>";
   }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Thanks again to everyone on this site, really appreciated.